# How to do bold and simple text in the same line using the echo in php

Tags: php, html, button, echo

I want the output from the echo function like this type:
**Group:** Monocot

But my output is showing like this:
**Group: Monocot**

My code is given bellow:

```
echo '<div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 150px;"> Bengali Name : '.$row['banglaname'].'</div>';
```

How do align `central` a button in PHP?

My code is given below:

```
<button onClick="window.print()">Print this page</button>
```

Comment: I see `Bengali Name` not `group`. Assuming `Monocot` is `$row['banglaname']` you need to restyle that output. Currently it is part of the `font-weight: bold`.

Comment: Use css `font-weight: bold`. or `<b></b>` HTML tags where you need. Only around the `Bengali Name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<div><span style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 150px;">Bengali Name :</span> '.$row['banglaname'].'</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks but button ?

Comment: <button style="text-align: center;" onClick="window.print()">Print this page</button>

Answer (score 0):

You change code:

```
echo '<div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 150px;"> Bengali Name : '.$row['banglaname'].'</div>';
```

To

```
echo '<div style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; margin-left: 150px;"> <span style="font-weight: bold;">Bengali Name</span> : '.$row['banglaname'].'</div>';
```